# Who owns the Riddle house by the time of "Goblet of Fire"?

Tags: harry-potter

In the first chapter of *Goblet of Fire*, it is mentioned that the Riddle house is currently owned by someone "for tax reasons". Do we ever learn who this man is? Is there any canon information on this?

It might be either a follower of Lord Voldemort or himself, or might it even be owned by the Ministry of Magic, or someone else? Of course, maybe a random man actually owns the Riddle House for tax reasons. Still, I am curious.

Comment: Edward Nigma.  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riddler  :)

Comment: Now, even Voldemort can't let a Vampire into his own house.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As far as I know, the Riddle House is owned by some random property investor (for lack of a better term) who bought it for, as your question says, tax purposes. I don't think it was a Death Eater because Voldemort took great care to hide his Muggle paternity from the world -- even in *Order of the Phoenix*, Bellatrix Lestrange is shocked at Harry's assertion that Voldemort is a half-blood.

> ‘Yeah,’ said Harry, maintaining his tight grip on the glass ball, expecting another attempt to bewitch it from him. ‘Yeah, I’ve got no problem with saying Vol—’
>   ‘Shut your mouth!’ Bellatrix shrieked. ‘You dare speak his name with your unworthy lips, you dare besmirch it with your halfblood’s tongue, you dare –’
>   ‘Did you know he’s a half-blood too?’ said Harry recklessly. Hermione gave a little moan in his ear. ‘Voldemort? Yeah, his mother was a witch but his dad was a Muggle – or has he been telling you lot he’s pure-blood?’
>   ‘STUPEF—’
>   ‘NO!’
>   A jet of red light had shot from the end of Bellatrix Lestrange’s wand, but Malfoy had deflected it[.]
>   <sub>*Order of the Phoenix* - pages 691-692 - Bloomsbury - chapter thirty-five, *Beyond the Veil*</sub>

There is no indication in the books, in any JKR interview that I know of, or at Pottermore that would suggest anyone other than a wealthy Muggle owns the Riddle House. From Pottermore:

[image: Screenshot of The Riddle House section in the *Goblet of *Fire* section of Pottermore]

Comment: I thought so, but was curious if maybe I missed something. And +1 for the disproof of my death-eater theory!

Comment: Thanks! It was an interesting theory, though, one I'd never thought of. New ideas are a good thing! :)